# How can I make the following class immutable?

Tags: java, immutability, date

I know I need to make `Date` immutable. However, I am not sure what else needs to be amended to ensure the class is immutable. `final` has been declared for the class and its methods.

```
public final class Journal {
    private final Set<Article> edition;
    private final Date pubDate;

    public Journal(Article [] contents, Date d) {
        edition = new TreeSet<Article>();
        for(int i=0; i <contents.length; i++)
        edition.add(contents[i]);

        pubDate = d;
    }

    public Set<Article> getArticles() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet(edition);
    }

    public Date getDate() { return pubDate; }
}
```

Comment: You need to return a copy of your `Date` object, otherwise you can change it with the object returned by `getDate()`.

Comment: Change `Date` to `Instant`.

Comment: When you pass any object to a class it is always a good idea to make a defensive copy of it so if the original is altered it wont affect the class. And when returning objects, return copies for the same reason.  Depending on when you should do one or the other or both depends on the nature of the application.

Comment: @Thilo I know Date is now legacy code, but thank you for pointing it out as I've just read up on the properties of Instant.

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of immutability. If you want standard immutability, that means every instance variable is `final` and there are no setters. If you want deep immutability, then your class must be immutable, but so must all of its instance variables. Alternatively, you can have your getters only return copies of your instance variables (ensuring that they will never change within your class). However, this carries a not insignificant performance cost and can create technical debt later on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Date` class you are using in `java.util.Date`. So, Date is mutable in java (not sure what is the reason). So, you should return a copy of pubDate.

```
public Date getDate() 
{
 return pubDate.clone();
}
```

Also, A new class has added in [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) which is immutable. I would suggest to use that if you your program does not require `java.util.Date` specifically.

**EDIT:** As per the suggestion in comment Date#clone can lead to problem as Date can be sub classed. Use `new Date(pubDate.getTime())` for copying the Date object.

Comment: I'd strongly discourage you to use the `clone` method. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61853971/5640649) to find out why

Comment: @lealceldeiro I agree with you we should not use clone on non-final class. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The best advice I could give you is to use `Instant` (or `LocalDateTime` or  `ZonedDateTime`) in place of a `Date` because `Instant` (and the other `java.time` classes) are immutable. `Date` is obsolete and should no longer be used. But, if you need to stick to this code then you could do *defensive copies*, something like the following:

```
public Journal(Article [] contents, Date d) {
    // ...
    pubDate = new Date(d.getTime());
}

// ...

public Date getDate() {
    return new Date(pubDate.getTime());
}
```

Notice here that the **`Date.clone`** method was **not used**. This is because `Date` is non-final, so the `clone` method is not guaranteed to return an object whose class is `java.util.Date`, it could return an instance of an untrusted subclass that is specifically designed with malicious intentions.

Comment: Hi, this is what I had, although I forgot to defensively copy the constructor, too. I was not aware of clone but it is good that you highlighted why not to use it. Thank you.

Comment: @JayG you're welcome :) Please, remember to up-vote (and maybe mark as accepted) the answer if it fits your needs.